# Submitting Form in MVC 5 model is null in controller post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

After post I am getting List in model is null
my model is has a property which is the list of vwLog.

```
public class CreateLogViewModel
{
    public List<vwLog> LogData;
}
```

In view I used that model and used foreach loop to assign the value in text control

```
@model CreateLogViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateLog", "Log", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    foreach (var item in Model.LogData)
    {
        <table>            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.LogID)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.AgencyBillingCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.LicenseNumber)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
    <div class="col-xs-12" align="center">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" id="Submit">
    </div>
}
```

My Controller is

In Get method  I am assigning the value in LogData object which is the collection of vwlog.

```
public ActionResult CreateLog(CreateLogViewModel model)
{
   model.LogData = GetDate();
   return View(model);
 }
```

I update some value of the list on the screen and try to save  that, but I am getting model.LogData null in Post.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateLog(CreateLogViewModel model, string submit)
{
    if (model.LogData != null)
    { 
        do this...
    }
}
```

I update some value of the list on the screen and try to save  that, but I am getting model.LogData null in Post. model is not null, but the collection object is null.
Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Not relevant to question, but for security I strong suggest using @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your view and authenticate the token in your controller with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop (refer the dupe) and you model must contain properties, not fields as NightOwl888 has indicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MVC model binder doesn't work with class fields:

```
public class CreateLogViewModel
{
    // This is a field
    public List<vwLog> LogData;
}
```

you *must* use properties:

```
public class CreateLogViewModel
{
    // This is a property
    public List<vwLog> LogData { get; set; }
}
```

> NOTE: You also need to make sure your `vwLog` type has public read-write properties for it to work.

Comment: Hey thanks... It works I did couple of changes including converting that to property.  So now model    public List<vwLog> LogData { get; set; } and controller is  --    List<vwLog> LogList = new List<vwLog>();
                LogService service = new LogService();
                LogList = getdata()                model.LogData = LogList;